# Atom as editor for mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb, atom-editor

I'm just trying to use Atom as editor in mongodb shell. I open mongo shell and declare EDITOR:

*EDITOR='c:/users/me/appData/local/atom/bin/atom.cmd'*

When I try to edit some function as in:

*edit myFunction*

Atom loads but last a lot to respond. It loads lots of files in its tree at the left, and keeps unresponsive. It even shows a modal: "Editor is not responding ...". 
When I just double click that file (atom.cmd) in Windows Explorer, it opens Atom without any problems. 
What am I missing here? 
Many thanks and bye ...